# Return the textScore using the mongo C driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I'm trying to recreate the following query using the mongo-c-driver.

```
db.djnNews.find({"date":"2014-02-06",$text:{$search:"GOOG"}},{score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

The text index is working fine. I can run:

```
query = BCON_NEW("$query","{","date",x->s,"$text","{","$search",y->s,"}","}"
```

Is there a way to include the $meta part into this query? Do I have to project it out in a certain way?

Comment: Andrea did you ever get an answer to this?